# How can I refer to an existing class in SCSS?

Tags: css, sass

I am using Bootstrap 5 & SCSS for my CSS definition. I know I can include `p-2` in html for padding. But how can I refer to that padding in SCSS itself? I don't want to override anything, I just want to be able to do, say:

```
.x {
  color: $gray2;
  padding: //one that is same for p-2 - whatever it is
}
```

I don't want to give that padding the exact px value, because that might change...

Comment: As you can see, this isn't a Bootstrap question. Also, don't put tags in titles. See [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are most likely looking for the [`extend`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/extend/) property.

Assuming p-2 looks something like this.

```
.p-2 {
   padding: 2rem;
}
```

Then using extend on your class

```
.x {
  @extend .p-2;
  color: $gray2;
}
```

Would give you this in the final css.

```
.x {
  padding: 2rem;
  color: $gray2;
}
```